# Is it possible to use gcc's linker in conjunction with dlopen?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

So, I have a program that makes use of the `xerces-c` c++ library. I am trying to modify it to not require the library be present when the program is run, since there are parts of it that can be run independently. Is is possible to accomplish this using `dlopen()` to load the library, while still using the linker in gcc to resolve symbols at compile time? Maybe I'm missing something but the xerces-c API seems very difficult to use with `dlsym()`, which is why I am trying to find a workaround.

Comment: Write do-nothing stubs for all those functions and recompile without linking to the shared lib and linking to your stubs instead?

Comment: @user2225104 I still want to be able to use xerces-c if it is present, I just want to avoid `ld` killing my program off the bat when it isn't there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution in cases like this would be to split your program into two parts, a main program that doesn't have a `xerces-c` dependency, and a shared library that does. Then you `dlopen` your shared library, which loads `xerces` and uses it. In this way you can define your own library API, basically.

Comment: I already have a single class which handles the interface with xerces, so this is probably the best solution.